# Buffer overflow wrong variable changing value

Tags: c, stack, buffer-overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test(void)
{
  int a=0,b=0;
  char buf[4];
  gets(buf);
  printf("a:%d b:%d",a,b);
}

int main()
{
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

Question is why with input:aaaaa a is becoming 97 instead of b?From the way variables are declared inside test when buf overflows  shouldn't it  affect first b and then a?

Comment: did you find an answer? you should mark the most helpful as the selected answer if you did.

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` variables will not be necessarily contiguous to the variable `buf`. Consequently, the overflow of the variable `buf`, has nothing to do with the possible values of `a` and `b`. The behaviour will be undefined.

However, it is important to mention that the **C** standard will store all of the arrays, such as buf, in continuous memory location.

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) you can check the documentation:

> An array is a series of elements of the same type placed in contiguous
>   memory locations that can be individually referenced by adding an
>   index to a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behaviour is undefined.  There's nothing in the language standard about the relative locations of different variables in a function, and there's definitely no guarantees about what will happen in a buffer overflow situation.